# Creating a function that will check the GET global for the 'page' variable and return the value

Tags: php

I am trying to create a function that will check the GET global for the 'page' variable and return the value and then assign that value to a variable.

```
$title = "Links";
if(isset($_GET['page']))
    $title = check($_GET['page']);
```

Comment: show us your best attempt (code) and share with us what doesn't work as expected. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've got it. the `isset()` function checks to see if there's a value in `$_GET['page']`. It seems all you need to do is set that value to a variable. and return that variable.

```
if(isset($_GET['page']){
    $page = $_GET['page'];
    print_r($page);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, Could you show me an example of setting that value to a variable?